# Listing rows not only when criteria are met

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: 
1 dates - contains column date
2 book - contains columns room, date and surname
3 people - contains column surname

I am able to get dates where there were people in rooms on certain days within the range of dates.

```html
SELECT date, IFNULL(surname, 'ghost')
FROM book JOIN dates ON book.date=dates.date JOIN people ON people.surname=book.surname
WHERE room = 113 
AND date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-07'

+------------+-----------+
| Date       | Surname   |
+------------+-----------+
| 2015-01-02 | Surname 1 |
| 2015-01-05 | Surname 2 |
+------------+-----------+
```

How do I return a full list of dates, including those where there was nobody in a room so every date from given range is printed and if no people in the specified room, then 'ghost' is printed instead?

Comment: What is in the `dates` table?

Comment: only 1 column with dates in format yyyy-mm-dd, basically a calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT dates.date, IFNULL(book.surname, 'ghost')
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN book 
    ON  book.date=dates.date
    AND book.room = 113 
-- LEFT JOIN people ON people.surname=book.surname
WHERE dates.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-07'
```

Note that `book.room = 113` needs to be in the ON clause. Using it in the WHERE clause would convert the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN.